# Keeping Submit Button Disabled Until Form Fields Are Full

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

Would someone be able to take a look at my code and see what I'm missing here?

I have a multi-page form with quite a lot of inputs, and I would like to keep "next page" buttons and the final "submit" buttons disabled until all the fields are full.

I am trying to recreate the process on a smaller scale but in my tests, I cannot seem to re-enable the disabled submit input.  I've checked the console and the JS is logging the variable elements so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```js
function checkForm()
{
 var elements = document.forms[0].elements;

 var cansubmit= true;
 
 for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
 {
  if(elements[i].value.length == 0 || elements[i].value.length == "" || elements[i].value.length == null)
  {
   cansubmit = false;
  }
  document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = !cansubmit; 
 }
 
};
```

```html
<form>
 <label for="firstName">First Name:</label> <input type="text" id="firstName" onkeyup="checkForm()" />
 
 <br />
 
 <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label> <input type="text" id="lastName" onkeyup="checkForm()" />
 
 <button type="button" id="myButton" disabled="disabled">Test me</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `elements` array includes your `button`, which has no value. This will cause your loop to always evaluate to `cansubmit = false;`.

Try this instead: https://jsfiddle.net/e00sorLu/2/

```
function checkForm()
{
    var elements = document.forms[0].elements;

    var cansubmit= true;
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        if(elements[i].value.length == 0 && elements[i].type != "button")
        {
            cansubmit = false;
        }

    }

    document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = !cansubmit;  
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  I've been watching tutorial after tutorial but I knew something weird was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Answer was already accepted, but here are a few other things you might consider:

The way you have it set up now, for absolutely anything other than an empty string `""` you're setting `button.disabled = false` and enabling the button.

1. You're checking `value.length` 3 times, but you actually want to
   check `.value` instead. The `length` property is [only a numeric
   value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) for how many code units are in the string - it won't ever be
   `""` or `null`, so the only thing you're really checking is the very
   first condition for an empty string of length 0.

   You're also not accounting for multiple white spaces in a blank string, so `"    "` would be valid) ... or
   special characters, so this would be valid: `(function goodByeWorld(evil){//do the bad things})();`
2. You're running the `checkForm()` function on all form elements
   (including the `<button>`) after every single keystroke. This is unnecessary.

   Aside from including `<button>`, which was pointed out in the accepted answer & will always cause this to fail, you should either validate each individual form element with inline error checking
   (preferable), or validate all of them once just prior to submission (preferable to server-side validation & kicking it back after submission).

   You could bind to `onblur()` instead and send the current element's value as an argument once that field loses focus. e.g. change to: `function checkValue(value) {//validate the value}`) and either `onblur = checkValue(this)` in the HTML or preferably a non-inline event handler that lives in the JS file instead.

   You could still do it `onkeyup = checkValue(this)` to check after every keystroke, but change the function to only check 1 element instead of checking t.h.e. e.n.t.i.r.e. f.o.r.m. dozens of times.

   This approach would let you individually keep track of each separate form element's validity (lots of options here depending on what "valid" means - store an array of values, objects with values or "valid/invalid" flags, etc, switch on the field labels to validate `this` for different types of information). You can run additional validation on the individual elements as well (e.g. min/max name length, eliminating special characters, etc), and display real-time error checking messages next to each form element.
3. You're defaulting to `cansubmit = true` which doesn't make much sense, given what you intend for this code to do. Using `!cansubmit` only serves to confuse yourself & others reading the code. For readability, consider inverting it to `disableSubmit` so it's in sync with the `button.disabled` state, which should only be `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this breakdown. You've given me some wonderful points to think about, especially number 2.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use jQuery.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkForm() {
            var cansubmit = false;
            $('form input[type="text"]').each(function (index, element) {
                if (element.value == "") {
                    cansubmit = true;
                }
            });
            document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = cansubmit;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Those variable names would make a programmer's head spin! ;)

Comment: Updated as requested ;)